# Fonts and python TypeError: expected string

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, truetype

i'm tring to create image through my application but i got no luck so far

I tried to create the image by simple script and it work like what i want but when i insert the code in my application i got strange error i don't know why this happen

Here is my simple script which work fine :

```
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf",24)
img=Image.new("RGBA", (600,200),"white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((400, 150),"sasa","black",font=font)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img.save("image.png")
```

but when i try to use it in my web application to create the image i got an error

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pillow-2.5.1-py2.7-win32.egg\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 266, in text
    mask, offset = font.getmask2(text, self.fontmode)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pillow-2.5.1-py2.7-win32.egg\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 152, in getmask2
    size, offset = self.font.getsize(text)
TypeError: expected string
```

and here is my code in my web app :

```
 img = Image.new("RGBA", (template_id.cheque_width, template_id.cheque_height), "white")
 draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
 if template_id.cheque_title_print:
           draw.text((template_id.cheque_title_margin_top, template_id.cheque_title_bottom),
                              template_id.cheque_title, "black",
                              font=ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', template_id.cheque_title_font_size))

#these is the values in the code
#template_id.cheque_width=600
#template_id.cheque_height=200
#template_id.cheque_title_margin_top=100
#template_id.cheque_title_bottom)=100
#template_id.cheque_title_print=True
# template_id.cheque_title="some_string"
#template_id.cheque_title_font_size=24
```

i know that it access the font file but why this error ? and how could i solve it ?

Comment: are you sure that `template_id.cheque_title` is a string? what if you do `assert isinstance(template_id.cheque_title, str), "was not a string: was type {0.__class__}:  {0!r}".format(template_id.cheque_title)` right above the line that raises the error in your actual code.

Comment: Thanks :)  my mistake , i didn't notice , i thought the problem is in the font file :) 

Thanks again